# Composer error while Composer update in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I have a Laravel project in, which laravel version is 8.75 and php version is 7.4.
When I upload my project in cpanel and go to terminal and run 'composer update' command ,it shows this type of error. I search this error but couldn't find any solution.

$ composer update

Composer is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have the PHP curl extension enabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
Failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found)

update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] []...

See this image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh1rl.png)

Comment: update your php.ini to set `allow_url_fopen=1` I thought this message made that pretty clear

Comment: Please do not run `composer update` after deploying your application!

Comment: Also, what have you tried to reoslve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable allow_url_fopen. here are the ref links how to do that

[allow_url_fopen cpanel](https://chemicloud.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-or-disable-allow_url_fopen-in-cpanel/)

[allow_url_fopen cpanel](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053203413-Changing-the-allow-url-fopen-Setting-for-PHP)

Comment: I enabled "allow_url_fopen" in cpanel but its not work. Then I go to WHM panel and enabled this extension . Now it worked!! Thanks for giving Idea.

Comment: Nice to hear that it is solved ......

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable curl extension and allow_url_fopen in your php.ini file.

## Method 1

Open your Terminal and run below command to show php.ini path.

```
php --ini
```

[image]

Open `php.ini` file then Search for `extension=curl` and Uncomment it by removing the semi-colon( ; ) in front of it.

```
// Before
;extension=curl

// After
extension=curl
```

then Search for `allow_url_fopen` and Change Value to On.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

## Method 2

1. Open your cPanel then Search for PHP and Click on MultiPHP INI Editor

[image]

2. Click on Editor Mode

[image]

3. Select Domain you are working on

[image]

4. Copy below lines and Paste in your PHP INI Editor

```
extension=curl
allow_url_fopen = On
```

5. Click on Save Button

[image]

Comment: I upload my project in cpanel, where the php.ini file

Comment: @e_mon Please check again my answer I have Added Second Method you can follow in your cPanel.

Comment: Yes,
First time I enabled this but it's not work.
Then I go to WHM panel, and enabled this extension, and also anothers.
Then it worked.

Comment: How this will work for the Cpanel. I have tried. It's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "`allow_url_fopen`" module through php in your cpanel, you can easily use the cpanel dashboard and navigate to "select php version" and there you can enable/disable all the modules you need, also you can change the php version if you so desire.
and as a recommendation, delete the composer.lock file and use `composer install` instead

Comment: I enabled "allow_url_fopen" in cpanel but its not work. 
Then I go to WHM panel and enabled this extension . Now it worked!!
Thanks for giving Idea.

Comment: @MdKhairulIslamEmon Maybe your CPanel account did not have enough permissions for modifying configurations. and maybe because the PHP version is inherited from WHM so it obeys it's commands